# Run time error in Modal popup extender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

when im using modal popup extender in asp.net pages i got "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '_popupElement.parentNode' is null or not an object" this is run time error every time. does anybody know the overcome this problem.

this is my modalpopup tag

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `Visisbilty = "false"` attribute for the target Panel control. The  modal popup will handle visiblity for you.  Additionally check the page codebehind to NOT set the visibilty to false of the target Panel. Let the pop-up do the magic!

Comment: I have a further problem that the PopupPanel was outside my Popup-Button, so it was shown by load, but moving the panel inside another soled this.

Comment: Now my Popup-button does postback, so I have to find out how to remove  that, else the Popup.windows disappers again.